# .plot() command does not display anything

Tags: python, plot, osmnx

I have this code based on this question, just a different point [Extract constrained polygon using OSMnx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59287237/extract-constrained-polygon-using-osmnx)

I am trying to plot the block in which the point is located but it does nothing, it just prints "Done" but I cannot see any image

```
import osmnx as ox
import geopandas as gpd
import shapely

point = (50.090464, 14.400070)

streets_graph = ox.graph_from_point(point, distance=500, network_type='drive')
streets_graph = ox.project_graph(streets_graph)

streets = ox.save_load.graph_to_gdfs(streets_graph, nodes=False, edges=True,
                                     node_geometry=False, fill_edge_geometry=True)

point = streets.unary_union.centroid

polygons = shapely.ops.polygonize(streets.geometry)
polygons = gpd.GeoSeries(polygons)

target = polygons.loc[polygons.contains(point)]

target_streets = streets.loc[streets.intersection(target.iloc[0]).type == 'MultiLineString']

ax = target_streets.plot()
gpd.GeoSeries([point]).plot(ax=ax, color='r')

print("Done")
```

I do not think this may help but I am using Visual Studio Code

Thank you very much

Comment: What happens if you do `gpd_plt = gpd.GeoSeries([point]).plot(ax=ax, color='r'); gpd_plt.show()`?

Comment: It raises Attribute Error "AxesSubplot object has no attribute "show"

Comment: What happens if you run your code from an interactive Python console session? (If Visual Studio Code doesn't have such a console, you could try the one from Spyder.)

Comment: You need to import matplotlib to show the plot. See this question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/223653/cannot-get-plot-in-geopandas-to-produce-a-map-of-the-geodataframe

Comment: Thank you both for help, importing matplotlib solved my problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since my comment answered your question, I will summarize it here for other people:

When using plotting library dependent on matplotlib, like geopandas or seaborn, you will need to import matplotlib in order to show the plot. The way matplotlib is imported will depend on whether you are using Jupyter or simple scripting (.py) files.

For Jupyter you need to import it like this:

```py
%matplotlib inline
```

For simple scripting (.py) file  you need to import it like this:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Then when you want to show your plot you simply do

```py
plt.show()
```

Hope it helps!